# Facebook & Twitter Like Buttons Slowing Page Load

Tags: jquery

I've been testing page speed and noticed that if I remove these 2 buttons the page load speed drops by around 3 seconds from 4 seconds to 1 second. Therefore it would obviously be of great advantage to speed to load of these buttons or otherwise remove them.

I'd like to keep them and I'm looking at how to speed them up. I read about Aync loading and currently for Twitter I load the script at the bottom of the page after page load (note: script loads just before the end body tag):

```
$(window).load(function() {
    !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.async=true;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
});
```

Note: I can see the delay on sites like http://www.webpagetest.org.

Question:
Is there a way to load this onto the page so its not included in the initial page load?

**Maybe once the page is loaded I could wait for an event (mouse movement) and then load these scripts? This should/could remove there delayed load from the initial page load.**

Note: I've tried different jquery options like below but these still include this in the initial page load:

```
$(window).load(function() {
$(function() {
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend putting the twitter/facebook files you are referencing on your local server. They can get bogged down at times from overusage.